# How to solve complex error for quadric surfaces?

Tags: matlab

I need help drawing this with MatLab. I get an error regarding complex values:

> error: mesh: X, Y, Z arguments must be real

My code is:

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(-3:0.1:3);
z = sqrt(9.*(y.^2-x.^2));
surf(x,y,z);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parametrization is really bad. For any |y| < |x| there is no real z to fulfill your equation and thus no point on the surface. That is the reason why you get complex values there.

When you parametrize y by x and z and you use both the positive and the negative y values you get the same surface as WolframAlpha:

```
[x,z] = meshgrid(-3:0.1:3);
y = sqrt(z.^2/9+x.^2);
surf(x,y,z);
hold on
surf(x,-y,z);
```

EDIT: Actually WolframAlpha uses a parametrization like this:

```
[y, angle] = meshgrid(-4:0.2:4, linspace(0,2*pi, 100));
x = y .* sin(angle);
z = 3*y .* cos(angle);
surf(x,y,z)
axis equal
```